# Firefox lightweight-theme-list-change event not sent?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a FF extension that I want notified when the lightweight theme list is changed.  Here's the code:

```js
var PesonaSwitcherObserver = {

    register: function() {
        PersonaSwitcher.log ("in register");
        var observerService =
            Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.addObserver(PesonaSwitcherObserver,
            "lightweight-theme-list-change", false);
    },

    observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
        PersonaSwitcher.log ("in observe");
        switch (topic) {
            case 'lightweight-theme-list-change':
                PersonaSwitcher.subMenu();
                break;
        }
    },

    unregister: function() {
        PersonaSwitcher.log ("in unregister");
        var observerService =
            Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.removeObserver(PesonaSwitcherObserver,
            "lightweight-theme-list-change");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", PesonaSwitcherObserver.register, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", PesonaSwitcherObserver.unregister, false);
```

The log receives the "in register", but no "in observes" when I add or remove personas.  I've even looked at LightweightThemeManager.jsm and

```js
function _updateUsedThemes(aList) {
```

calls

```js
Services.obs.notifyObservers(null, "lightweight-theme-list-changed", null);
```

Anyone know why or have a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the call to `observerService.addObserver()` fails - please check the Error Console (press Ctrl-Shift-J to open it). Your observer doesn't implement `QueryInterface` function and the observer service will explicitly check whether `nsIObserver` is implemented. This function is easiest to implement using [XPCOMUtils.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm). If you don't want to import it into the global scope (you probably don't since your code seems to run from an overlay) you can do it like this:

```js
var PesonaSwitcherObserver = {
    QueryInterface: Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", null)
                              .XPCOMUtils
                              .generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIObserver]),
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly edited your response instead of following up :-( Still learning about how to navigate SO...

Comment: @user1377029: No problem - your edits go into a review queue and I guess that the edit was rejected.

Comment: Good!  It looks like that isn't the event I wanted to monitor anyway.  I'm now looking at making onInstail/onUninstall public in LieghtweightThemeManager.jsm.  Thanks again!